# Inconsistent HTTP trigger behaviour to Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, httprequest, firebase-hosting

I'm having trouble reliably triggering a Firebase Cloud Function via the HTTP trigger method. It doesn't work in all browsers, and sometimes only works if you reload the page. The html webpage is hosted with Firebase Hosting.

Premise is simple, main html page has a button which when pressed, sends the HTTP request to the Cloud Function, and then navigates to another page saying done. The Cloud Function sends an FCM notification and works reliably when manually using the HTTP request url.

Is there something wrong with my HTTP request in `scripts.js`? What would make this very inconsistent behaviour? It works generally in Chrome, not in Firefox, and sometimes in Edge.

`index.html` looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel=icon href=favicon.ico>
    <title>Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>New heading</h1>
    <input type="button" value="Send FCM" onclick="doThing()">
    <script src="scripts.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

`scripts.js` looks like this

```
var request = require('request')

function doThing(){
    const url = '<HTTP request URL>';
    request(url, function(error, response, body){
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200){
            window.location.href = "outro.html";
        }
    })
}
```

and `outro.html` looks like this;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Title</title>
  <body>
    <h1>Cya</h1>
  </body>
  </body>
</html>
```

For clarity, this is the Cloud Function script:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
exports.sendNotification = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) =>{
    var topic = 'all';
    var payload = {
        notification:{
            title: 'Title!',
            body: 'Test!'
        },
    };
    return admin.messaging().sendToTopic(topic, payload).then((res) =>{
        response.status(200).send("ok");
        return console.log("Success:");
    }).catch((err) =>{
        console.log("Error: ", err);
        response.status(500).send("bad");
    });
});
```

All are deployed with `firebase deploy`.

Comment: Please edit the question to include your debugging information, especially the error you're getting.

Comment: @DougStevenson I can't find any errors in any of the Firebase logs, and from the Cloud Functions logs, it looks like the HTTP request is never getting there sometimes. That's the inconsistent behaviour. Even in the local Firebase emulator, if I click the button the first time, nothing happens, but if I go back and click it again, it works.

Comment: So, the error must be in the client app.

Comment: The Cloud Function logs to console on successful triggers, and those successful triggers aren't being seen some of the time, which makes me think it's not the client app.

Comment: OK, well, without debugging information, there's nothing we can do.  I'm noticing that you're not checking for any errors in the client request.

Comment: I appreciate your time and attention, and I'm sure you can see why I'm confused by this. Am I calling the HTTP request in the right manner? In terms of error checking in the client request, is that in scripts.js?

Comment: If something is going wrong, there should be an error.  You should check API calls for errors to find that out.  Log the arguments in your request callback to find out.